# a href error direct default aspx

Tags: asp.net, custom-errors

I have a url like : 120.xxx.xxx.xxx/myfile.pdf ,but it doesn't exist

and it not direct to my error.aspx

Can someone to tell me whats happened

and My web.config code

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: what is the domain of the site?

Comment: What is the url of your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because this is a static file and by default will bypass ASP.Net and just get served up by IIS. Try adding this to your `<system.webServer>` section of the web.config:

```
<handlers>
      <add name="PDFHandler-Integrated" path="*.pdf" verb="GET"
        type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler"
        requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Doing this will make it go through the ASP.Net pipeline so you can apply other functionality like Authentication/Role restrictions.